How can carpet be installed in rooms wider than the width of the carpet roll?
We have a main bedroom addition that we just had built that is 15 x 16 feet. We are getting ready to price carpet for the room and are realizing that it seems most carpet rolls are 12-15 feet.
I don't know much about carpet honestly, but I believe it is held down by tack strips, which would not be a good idea for the middle of a room.
Are we pretty much at a point where we need to consider something other than carpet? Most of the house is tile, and we wanted the bedrooms to be softer on the feet, but wondering if we may be out of of luck with that.
Any help or direction would be appreciate.

I've attempted to write a title question which reflects what you're asking. Please revise further as needed. See the [help] and take the [tour].

If you are going to install it yourself then there are a bunch of related questions. If you are getting it installed professionally (usually from the same place you buy the carpet) then they will normally send out a measurer who will figure out how many cuts of what size based on room layouts (gets complicated sometimes if there are 2 or 3 connected rooms with the same carpet in all rooms), roll size and other factors. (Source: I used to have a customer in the carpet business.)

You could also use tile, laminate etc. with either a very large rug or multiple smaller ones. The latter is quite common in parts of Scandinavia on hard floors (as well as downstairs in my house). But a decent professional carpet fitter can do a good job. You might want to get them to come out and discuss/quote before you commit to anything, because as well as making the seam practically invisible, they'll also arrange it in the room for subtlety and wear. A seam across a high traffic path will start to show fast sooner than one that doesn't cross the route to a doorway

Hint: If you buy a 15' wide roll of carpet, you align that dimension with the 15' dimension of the room and all is good. If you buy a 12' wide roll of carpet, you hire a pro to install it, or you deal with seams falling apart until you get enough DIY practice to finally get it right.

I don't see the problem? A 16 foot length of carpet, with a 15 foot width, will fit perfectly, unless the dimensions you have given us are more 'complicated' than they appear?

@MikeB if the room is even a tiny bit over 15ft (well, but more than the fraction of an inch it will be stretched by) it's not going to work. OTOH skirting boards (base boards) might reduce the room size to make it work.

Yes, you can install carpet in a room that is wider than the carpet roll. Installers use a seam sealing tape and a special iron to melt the glue in the tape. A good installer will know to keep the pile in the same direction. The result is a continuous carpet with no visible seams.

Though a lot of the "no visible seams" depends on both the quality of the installer, and also the carpet pattern itself.  Some are a lot easier to seam together (solid no-texture and only truly random little flecks of color) vs those with defined patterns or textures.

Depends on the carpet.  This house has one room with a seam.  You can just see it because the carpet doesn't lay quite the same there.

My 4 bedroom house has the same carpet laid throughout, and theres not a seam in sight - it’s absolutely perfect and looks and feels continuous throughout.  Carpets rubbish tho, but the installer was good

The first YouTube hit was this very convincing video of a pro with pro tools producing a zero visibility seam. Impressive. Thinking about it, the longer the carpet pile, the easier it is to make it invisible, probably. Hiding the seam would be harder with short, very smooth pile without a lot of structure.

Btw, check the question edit - the "Yes" doesn't quite fit the latest version ;-).

Or as a programmer: Its not a bug, its a feature! You could also cut the carpet in half and add another color row in the middle. Not saying you should, just saying you might use this to a "might aswell" :)
